# How to create Directory/Folder when using Magento?

Tags: magento, url

We are running magento on our site www.xsmoke.com. The site is international, so we are using "/country code" - e.g.www.xsmoke.com/de/ etc.

Now we would like to install wordpress in one of the languages only and we want the URL to be "xsmoke.com/de/blog".

But i can't create a folder on that location for the wordpress files because of magento.. Does anyone have an idea for a workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: ` i can't create a folder on that location for the wordpress files because of magento` ? Means ? You can simply put Wordpress htaccess file in Wpress folder.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you've set things up but it would be possible to do this by using the technique involving directories and symlinks for multiple websites (rather than have Magento include the store codes in the url).  See the below answer on how to do that;

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13171/multiple-country-specific-stores-on-the-same-domain-show-country-selection-firs#answer-13173

And you'd then just install Wordpress in the /de/blog directory.  Otherwise you might be better asking another question tagged with .htaccess and ask for a way to do a rewrite that would handle it in the context of Magento's existing rewrites.